# Trying to update TableView data source from within closure but items don't populate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to update a TableView through this API function, but my list doesn't actually populate and stay populated. I have discovered this is a closure issue, but I can't figure out where to write the [self.castMembers] in this to make it work.

https://github.com/gkye/TheMovieDatabaseSwiftWrapper/wiki/TV

The clientReturn seems to simply be if there is an error or not btw.

Thoughts on how I can fix this? I've tried many variations of where to put the brackets to no avail.

```
TVMDB.credits(tvShowID: 69050) {
            clientReturn, tvShow in
            tvShow?.cast.forEach({ (TVCastMDB) in
                self.castMembers.append([TVCastMDB.character!, TVCastMDB.name!])
            })
        }
```

Comment: i don't know what is your problem, could you make it clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `TVMDB.credits` triggers its closure on main thread, call reload Data once you update `castMembers` array

```
        TVMDB.credits(tvShowID: 69050) {[weak self] clientReturn, tvShow in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            tvShow?.cast.forEach({ (TVCastMDB) in
                self.castMembers.append([TVCastMDB.character!, TVCastMDB.name!])
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

If its not being called on main, you can always use `DispatchQueue.main` to switch to main thread

```
        TVMDB.credits(tvShowID: 69050) {[weak self] clientReturn, tvShow in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            tvShow?.cast.forEach({ (TVCastMDB) in
                self.castMembers.append([TVCastMDB.character!, TVCastMDB.name!])
            })
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

Above answer assumes you have your tableView's data source set appropriately and you have implemented all the necessary/non-optional methods of tableView's data source like `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt indexPath`

Comment: @kouskous: Glad I could help :) Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tickmark next to answer